# Drupal Commerce - How to programmatically create a fixed coupon?

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce

What is the best practice for creating a fixed amount coupon programmatically in a custom module?

I want to calculate a value and then create a coupon code for that fixed amount it programmatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out answer here:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88484/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-create-a-commerce-coupon-fixed-amount

Also check the tutorial from within the answer.